# Need a string library for JAVA ME

Tags: java, string, java-me

Can someone suggest me some JAVA string library for JAVA ME that includes basic string functions like trim,tolower,toupper,replace,substring,etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J2ME has these functions with the String class. [image]

or maybe I just mis-understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should just check the [JavaME](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) API....

Answer (score 0):

It's already included with the String class.